# How to conditional render GetxController

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

If I want to get the GetxController according to the previous route name, how should i code this snippet?

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    MyGetxController? controller;
    if (Get.previousRoute != '/home') {
      controller = Get.find();
    }
    ...
  }
```

The MyGetxController is already put in other route except the home route.

Answer (score 0):

Through not the best practice, i separate any potential condition in its isolate.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (Get.previousRoute != '/home') {
      final MyGetxController? controller = Get.find();
      return ...
    } else {
      return ...
    }
  }
```